# Amazon S3 move files from S3 folder to Ec2 folder by preserving the directory structure

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cron

I have an Amazon S3 bucket and EC2 instance with below folder structure, I need to run a cron job to move files from folder1, folder2, folder3 from Amazon S3 to folder1, folder2, folder3 on EC2 by maintaining a folder structure i.e. files under folder1 on S3 should move to folder1 in Ec2, folder2 on S3 should move to folder2 in Ec2 and so on. The folder names in Amazon S3 and Ec2 will be same.

```
S3
bucket
     .
     .
     .
     /folder1
     /folder2
     /folder3

EC2

main
     .
     .
     /folder1
     /folder2
     /folder3
```

I tried using

```
*/5 * * * * aws s3 mv s3://bucket/ main/ --recursive
```

But it is not giving desired results as the entire folder structure is being moved. Is there is a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Should be `mv s3://bucket/* main/` to move each folder.